# Select only the columns in a dataframe which have the same column names as another dataframe in R

Tags: r, select, dplyr, subset, rbind

I have several datasets which looks like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame (
A1_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
A2_01 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
A3_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
L1_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
L2_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),2),
gender = c(rep("M",5), rep("F",5)),
ID = c("A12345", "A23456", "A34767", "A34567", "A45678", "A67891", "A78910", "A91011", 
     "A10111", "A11121"))

df2 <- data.frame (
A1_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
A2_01 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
A3_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
Z4_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
Z5_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),2),
gender = c(rep("M",5), rep("F",5)),
ID = c("Q12345", "Q23456", "Q34767", "Q34567", "Q45678", "Q67891", "Q78910", "Q91011", 
     "Q10111", "Q11121"))
```

I want to rbind all these datasets together, to form one larger dataset. To do this, I need each dataset to have the same column names. I have therefore tried to subset all the datasets to contain only the columns / variables they have in common.

This is what I tried to do, but this doesn't work.

```
test <- df1 %>%
 select(names(df1) %in% names(df2))
```

My desired output would be:

```
df3 <- data.frame (
A1_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
A2_01 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
A3_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
age = c(rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),2), rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"),2)),
gender = c(rep("M",5), rep("F",5), rep("M",5), rep("F",5)),
ID = c("A12345", "A23456", "A34767", "A34567", "A45678", "A67891", "A78910", "A91011", 
     "A10111", "A11121", "Q12345", "Q23456", "Q34767", "Q34567", "Q45678", "Q67891", "Q78910", "Q91011", 
     "Q10111", "Q11121") )
```

Following the responses below, my code is now very long. Because I have multiple datasets, this is very time consuming. The purpose of this exercise was to subset only the columns which were in common across all six datasets, so I don't want to use bind_rows.

I have ended up writing iterative code which looks like the code below.   Does anyone know if there's a more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

```
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y2A), names(NZHS_Y3A))
NZHS_Y2_3 <- rbind(NZHS_Y2A[nm], NZHS_Y3A[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y3A), names(NZHS_Y4A))
NZHS_Y3_4 <- rbind(NZHS_Y3A[nm], NZHS_Y4A[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y4A), names(NZHS_Y5A))
NZHS_Y4_5 <- rbind(NZHS_Y4A[nm], NZHS_Y5A[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y5A), names(NZHS_Y6A))
NZHS_Y5_6 <- rbind(NZHS_Y5A[nm], NZHS_Y6A[nm])

nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y2_3), names(NZHS_Y3_4))
NZHS_Y2_4 <- rbind(NZHS_Y2_3[nm], NZHS_Y3_4[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y3_4), names(NZHS_Y4_5))
NZHS_Y3_5 <- rbind(NZHS_Y3_4[nm], NZHS_Y4_5[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y4_5), names(NZHS_Y5_6))
NZHS_Y4_6 <- rbind(NZHS_Y4_5[nm], NZHS_Y5_6[nm])

nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y2_4), names(NZHS_Y3_5))
NZHS_Y2_5 <- rbind(NZHS_Y2_4[nm], NZHS_Y3_5[nm])
nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y3_5), names(NZHS_Y4_6))
NZHS_Y3_6 <- rbind(NZHS_Y3_5[nm], NZHS_Y4_6[nm])

nm = intersect(names(NZHS_Y2_5), names(NZHS_Y4_6))
NZHS_Ad_2_6 <- rbind(NZHS_Y2_5[nm], NZHS_Y4_6[nm])
```

Comment: `nm = intersect(names(df1), names(df2)); rbind(df1[nm], df2[nm])`

Comment: Edited to show how to extend this into a list of dataframes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to get the set of columns that are in common between both data frames, as noted in the [comment by d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643840/select-only-the-columns-in-a-dataframe-which-have-the-same-column-names-as-anoth#comment90251926_51643840).

An alternative is to use `dplyr`'s `bind_rows`, which allows you to match columns that match and fill those that don't with missings. This might be a more desirable output in some circumstances.

EDIT: to deal with many dataframes, you should store them in a list and use `reduce` to get the intersection of all of the dataframes. This applies the function to the first two elements in the list, then the result of that and the third element, and so on. Then you can `map_dfr` over the list to select only the shared columns from each data frame and row bind them together (or alternatively `map` and then `do.call(rbind, .)` if you want to use `rbind`. Not desired in this case, but `bind_rows` accepts a list as input directly.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  A1_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  A2_01 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  A3_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  L1_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  L2_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"), 2),
  gender = c(rep("M", 5), rep("F", 5)),
  ID = c(
    "A12345", "A23456", "A34767", "A34567", "A45678", "A67891", "A78910", "A91011",
    "A10111", "A11121"
  )
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  A1_01 = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  A2_01 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  A3_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  Z4_02 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  Z5_02 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  age = rep(c("40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64"), 2),
  gender = c(rep("M", 5), rep("F", 5)),
  ID = c(
    "Q12345", "Q23456", "Q34767", "Q34567", "Q45678", "Q67891", "Q78910", "Q91011",
    "Q10111", "Q11121"
  )
)
library(tidyverse)
df_list <- list(df1, df2)
cols <- reduce(df_list, .f = ~ intersect(colnames(.x), colnames(.y)))
map_dfr(df_list, ~ .[cols])
#>    A1_01 A2_01 A3_02   age gender     ID
#> 1      1     1     0 40-44      M A12345
#> 2      0     1     0 45-49      M A23456
#> 3      0     1     0 50-54      M A34767
#> 4      1     0     1 55-59      M A34567
#> 5      0     1     0 60-64      M A45678
#> 6      1     0     1 40-44      F A67891
#> 7      0     0     0 45-49      F A78910
#> 8      1     0     1 50-54      F A91011
#> 9      0     0     1 55-59      F A10111
#> 10     0     0     0 60-64      F A11121
#> 11     1     1     0 40-44      M Q12345
#> 12     0     1     0 45-49      M Q23456
#> 13     0     1     0 50-54      M Q34767
#> 14     1     0     1 55-59      M Q34567
#> 15     0     1     0 60-64      M Q45678
#> 16     1     0     1 40-44      F Q67891
#> 17     0     0     0 45-49      F Q78910
#> 18     1     0     1 50-54      F Q91011
#> 19     0     0     1 55-59      F Q10111
#> 20     0     0     0 60-64      F Q11121
bind_rows(df_list)
#>    A1_01 A2_01 A3_02 L1_02 L2_02   age gender     ID Z4_02 Z5_02
#> 1      1     1     0     1     0 40-44      M A12345    NA    NA
#> 2      0     1     0     1     0 45-49      M A23456    NA    NA
#> 3      0     1     0     1     0 50-54      M A34767    NA    NA
#> 4      1     0     1     1     1 55-59      M A34567    NA    NA
#> 5      0     1     0     1     1 60-64      M A45678    NA    NA
#> 6      1     0     1     0     1 40-44      F A67891    NA    NA
#> 7      0     0     0     0     0 45-49      F A78910    NA    NA
#> 8      1     0     1     1     1 50-54      F A91011    NA    NA
#> 9      0     0     1     1     0 55-59      F A10111    NA    NA
#> 10     0     0     0     0     0 60-64      F A11121    NA    NA
#> 11     1     1     0    NA    NA 40-44      M Q12345     1     0
#> 12     0     1     0    NA    NA 45-49      M Q23456     1     0
#> 13     0     1     0    NA    NA 50-54      M Q34767     1     0
#> 14     1     0     1    NA    NA 55-59      M Q34567     1     1
#> 15     0     1     0    NA    NA 60-64      M Q45678     1     1
#> 16     1     0     1    NA    NA 40-44      F Q67891     0     1
#> 17     0     0     0    NA    NA 45-49      F Q78910     0     0
#> 18     1     0     1    NA    NA 50-54      F Q91011     1     1
#> 19     0     0     1    NA    NA 55-59      F Q10111     1     0
#> 20     0     0     0    NA    NA 60-64      F Q11121     0     0
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).